# Enable align buttons on toolbar in Netbean

Tags: netbeans, alignment

How can I enable align buttons on toolbar? I´m using Netbean v12

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout must be set to `Free Design` and you must have selected two or more components to have those buttons enabled.